# What are those 2 parts on my tab's circuit board?

Tags: recovery-mode, overheating

Can anyone tell me what those two pieces on the following image? (colored with yellow)
i suspect its the CPU and the Wifi but im not sure.
[image]

my issue here is that the temps on my tab is pretty hot (since a long time) 
i never had time to check but now this will change
The heat comes from the red area that i have selected but i dont see any other pieces that can cause the heat

idle temps are 40-50 (recovery mode) with my window open, cold air is comming into my room)
load temps are getting high as 91 (i got this when i was making a backup within the recovery mode.

My tab is an Samsung Galaxy TabPro 10.1

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be an end-user question.  Identifying the part won't change that it's generating heat or reduce the heat it generates.  A better question might be how to improve thermal throttling for your device (for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole piece of circuitry near the top seems to be the logic board for your tablet. This contains the flash memory and (what seems to be) the WiFi receiver and transmitter on it. If the highlighted chip which you think is the CPU is actually the flash memory chip, that would make sense with it overheating when you're making a backup. There's nothing on the underside of the board itself which could create heat (there could be something touching it on the other side, however if it's heating up the board to 91 degrees it would have to be very hot), just to note.

I don't believe the CPU, or GPU in fact, would be located on the logic board. Replacement ones can be bought (replacement logic boards, that is), however they aren't cheap and it might be better to get a new tablet. Also, if you do purchase a replacement one, it will have a different memory chip, and therefore will not contain any of the original data or files which the old one had. If it's getting as high as 91 degrees, I'd be thinking something's beginning to go wrong.

Comment: thanks for your answer, buying a new one is not a a option for me since its pretty expensive, i can however get something like a replacement part like i did before i switched one of the flex cables that wasnt working anymore.
if i read it correcly are you saying that flash chips are able to create heat??

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't see why the WiFi chip would generate heat, so I would assume it is the flash chip. But yes, almost every electronic IC generates heat as a by-product of the while operating process, the larger the circuitry inside the hotter it would get (technically this also depends on other factors as well, such as operating voltage, but that's not really that important now). If you're going to replace it, remember that you're also replacing all of the onboard memory, so make sure you back everything up. Also, make sure you know what you're doing when you replace it >

Comment: > and if you decide to replace it yourself, of course take care not to damage anything, either on the logic board or on anything else. I recommend taking it to a specialized dealer and maybe asking them what you should do, if not asking them to replace it maybe if they don't charge too much. And finally, make sure you're buying a genuine spare part - I wouldn't know how to confirm which dealers of spare electronic parts on the internet are reliable myself I'm afraid.

Comment: well aww...
replacing is not really an option for me then...
i could bring it back to store but since i rooted and reflashed the warranty is now void dam..

Comment: You could try somewhere that specializes in it nearby, if you have such a place. Not sure many places do.

Comment: And on a side note, there *could* be a CPU underneath the metal shield, but I highly doubt it. This is usually the case on small circuit boards where space is limited, such as in mobile phones - you may as well cover the whole circuitry as it's easier, and you may not have space to actually allow the metal shield to connect it to the circuit board anywhere else, if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks i will look for a specalist that does this kind of job
by the way i found out that when i turn off the screen the heat slowly fades away, while all the apps (i think) are still running including my music player, so i assume it has to do with the screen maaaybe? is there anything else then the connector that goes to the circuit board from the display?

Comment: Hmmm, this puts a different look on things. It could be the GPU, maybe that is underneath the metal shield, but I'm not sure it would be... however, I'm not an expert on the subject. If you do find a specialist, you could ask they exactly what they think is on the logic board. Reading an IFixIt article (https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Samsung+Galaxy+Tab+10.1+Motherboard+Replacement/18738), it says that the whole circuit board (including the part that produces heat) is the mother board. However your device looks different and is the "Pro" iteration, so I assume this article does not help with >

Comment: > your device. Also, there are 3 connectors on the back across the battery - yours only has two. However, I would consult a specialist or expert in this field - I am by no means one myself.